# How to place set of div's to center of the webpage dynamically

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I want to place a set of div's on the center of webpage and want to vary its size from center as per the length of username which is available in span class.

```css
.Parent1Div
{
  height:60px; 
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

.Parent2Div{
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;   
  max-height:30px;
  padding:0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

#Child2Div{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#Child2Div > div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <div class = "parent1div">
    
     <div class="parent2div" runat="server">
                    <div class="Child1Div"><img src="image1.jpg" /></div>
                    <div id="Child2Div" runat="server" class="ColStyle">
                        <span class="textclass ColStyle" id="username"  runat="server"></span>
                        <span class="ColStyle buttonclass">
                        span.....button for logout......</span>
                    </div>
      </div>
  ......Some content for Menu
    </div>
```

Here, parent1div is the main div and it holds content for menu.
Parent2Div holds some small sized images along with user name and logout button. I want the entire div's from parent2div to be placed in
the center of the page. Its width should vary as per size of the username but it should be positioned at the center every time. The name can be long or short and depending upon that ths size should increase or decrease from center.
ColStyle and textclass are the classes which holds some basic functions such as text color, size and padding.

I am not sure what I am missing, but when I use the above CSS, these div's move towards the left corner
of the page.
If I increase the webkit-transform to 50% for parent2div, it is moving to center but the width is
not getting adjusted on both sides from center for longer names. Rather, left side is at center
and width increases on right side alone (which does not make the entire div's center).

I want the div's from Parent2div to behave in the manner as that in below jfiddle, but I am not sure what I am missing and when I put everything back together, the div's are not getting positioned at the center and adjusting automatically.

https://jsfiddle.net/xrnsmywr/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your naming conventions -- you're using classes rather than IDs. You just got the naming slightly incorrect.

`.Parent1Div` should be `#parent1div`, and `.Parent1Div` should be `#parent2div`. For some reason you're using a class for `Child1Div`, but an ID for `Child2Div`. Simply make sure you use the correct naming combinations in both HTML and CSS, and you can easily alig with `text-align: center.

To centralise a `<div>` (or the image), you can use `margin: 0 auto`:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I've created a Fiddle showcasing the change in names, which can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ceyc5Lnt/).

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT:**

After modification to the original code, class names and IDs have been changed, but they are still inconsistent. You'll need to correct that by changing `.ParentDiv1` to `.parent1div` and `.ParentDiv1` to `.parent2div`.

A secondary line of text has been added, but no code actually centralises it. You'll also need to add:

```
.parent1div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I've created a new [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/4d75nuoj/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I made some updates to my question and jfiddle. I think I used the same way as you have mentioned and ultimately I expect the result in the same way as you have mentioned. Still it is not centering. It is getting placed to the left side and if I make -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%), they are moving to center but not getting positioned at the center and adjusting automatically.

Comment: The problem is definitely because of inconsistent / incorrect naming conventions. Please ensure that you have classes / IDs referenced correctly. Try things like `#parent1div { color: orange }` to ensure that you have referenced your classes / IDs correctly.

Comment: I have made sure the ID's and classes are consistent in my code (like how you have said) initially. I just made a mistake while posting the question here. Sorry about that. There is something else that is blocking.

Comment: Your names are **still** inconsistent. Please remember that class names are **case-sensitive**. Change it to `.parent1div` and `.parent2div`, and then add `.parent1div { text-align: center }`. You added the second line without adding any means to centralise it. I'll update my answer to cover this.